# mod_rewrite beginner: map files to php files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a simple rule such that:

`/page` gets implicitly routed to `/page.php`. Inversely, I'd like any direct access to `/page.php` to be redirected in the address bar to `/page`.

Currently I have:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But that does not handle the 2nd case. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to treat your second rule before your first one. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: This seems to work except that css/js files (linked to like c/main.css and lib/site.js) are not loaded.

Comment: i've updated the code to accommodate for that issue. Basically, i prevent the last rule from running if hte request is a file. Since php files are blocked upstream, they will have already been taken care of and it should work as you expect.